# Multiplying floats occasionally produces a large trail of decimals

Tags: python, floating-point

It's not really a major issue, but on occasion when I look for the output of a float number (usually to the thousandths place) and an int, I get a number that has the correct answer, but then a bunch of trailing zeroes and another integer. Here's some code I encountered this in, and my various tests to try isolating the problem:

Code:

```
def returnit():
    return float(17.556)

var1 = 17.556
var2 = (17.556 * 3)
print(returnit() * 3)
print(var1 * 3)
print(var2)
print(str(17.556 * 3))
print(17.556 * 3)
```

The output for all of them is `52.668000000000006`.

Honestly I'm just curious as to why this happens, and the sum of my research has yielded "uhh... floating points don't do amazingly with math sometimes?"

Comment: This is due to the nature of floating point numbers. See the linked question for a general discussion and more links on the topic.

Comment: And "uhh... floating points don't do amazingly with math sometimes?" just about sums it up. Or more accurately floating point numbers are an approximation to the so-called real numbers we learned about in high school algebra. They have some quirks like this due to the technicalities of representing numbers in a binary system with finite space.